cellSize calculation in Python
To create a raster file of cell size, which is similar to the function of cellSize function in terra library in R.
It takes input raster with whatever the input's projection, and calculate cellsize in m2 or km2.
The following code (even it seems not totally similar to what I calculate from R).
But it is somehow correct.
The problem is that it only returns the right value when input has projection of 'EPSG:4326'.
However, if an input has projection of, for example, 'EPSG:32647', the result is wrong.
How to solve it?
def cellSize(image, unit='m', meta: Optional[Dict]=None):
 import rasterio
 import numpy as np
 from rasterio.transform import from_origin
 from pyproj import CRS, Transformer

 if (isinstance(image, rasterio.DatasetReader)):
    # Read the spatial metadata
    transform = image.transform
    crs = image.crs
    width = image.width
    height = image.height
    #dtype = image.dtypes[0]
 else:
    if meta is None:
        raise ValueError('Please provide metadata of raster input')
    else:
        # Read the spatial metadata
        transform = meta['transform']
        crs = meta['crs']
        width = meta['width']
        height =meta['height']
        #dtype = meta['dtypes'][0]   

 if crs != 'EPSG:4326':
    raise ValueError('Image should have crs of "EPSG:4326", please project it using raster.project funtion')
 else:
    # Initialize the output area array
    area_array = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.float32)
    # Define a transformer to convert from the GeoTIFF CRS to WGS84 for latitude and longitude
    transformer = Transformer.from_crs(crs, 'EPSG:4326', always_xy=True)
    # Get the pixel size in map units (degrees for EPSG:4326)
    pixel_width_map, pixel_height_map = transform[0], -transform[4]
    # Calculate the Earth's radius in meters (WGS84)
    earth_radius = 6378137  # WGS84 semi-major axis in meters

    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            # Calculate the geographic coordinates of the pixel
            x, y = transform * (j, i)

            # Get the latitude and longitude of the pixel center
            lon, lat = transformer.transform(x, y)

            # Convert latitude and longitude to radians
            lat_rad = np.radians(lat)

            # Calculate the pixel size in meters
            pixel_width_m = pixel_width_map * (np.pi / 180) * earth_radius * np.cos(lat_rad)
            pixel_height_m = pixel_height_map * (np.pi / 180) * earth_radius

            # Calculate the area of the pixel in square meters
            area_m2 = pixel_width_m * pixel_height_m

            # Convert the area to the desired unit
            if (unit.lower() == 'm') or (unit.lower() == 'meter'):
                area_array[i, j] = area_m2
            elif (unit.lower() == 'ha') or (unit.lower() == 'hectare'):
                area_array[i, j] = area_m2 / 10_000 
            elif (unit.lower() == 'km') or (unit.lower() == 'kilometer'):
                area_array[i, j] = area_m2 / 1_000_000 
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Unsupported unit: {unit}")
    
    # Prepare metadata for the GeoTIFF
    metadata = {
        'crs': crs,
        'transform': transform,
        'width': width,
        'height': height,
        'dtype': np.float32
    }

    return area_array, metadata


If you have a pixel size of 1 by 1 meter in EPSG:32637, what does your code return?
